# How to clone a SWT control?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

In AWT/Swing, the control supports serialization. Easy cloning.

But how to clone SWT Control? For example, Tree.

I want to make a tool to realize cloning function by extracting data from controls. But it is unclear whether Eclipse provides such a tool.

Comment: No, it doesn't provide such a tool. I can't say I have ever found a need for this, what do you want to use it for? JFace has some Factory classes that can produce multiple copies of a control.

Comment: For example, Package Explorer, I want to display its contents in a dialog box, although I can set the parent to move it over and put it back after use

But it would be better if we could clone it.

So I plan to write a program to automatically complete, but only support tree? Or all controls? I didn't think clearly.

Comment: Package Explorer is not a single control, it is a large complex set of classes.

Comment: Yes, I don't need its functions. I just need data, which is only used for display. So I described the problem as Tree instead of TreeViewer

Comment: If you have a model and a viewer, you want to serialize the model (data) and not the viewer (UI widgets).